# Linking globals named 'fbad_Cocos2DGetGLViewController': symbol multiply defined

Tags: ios, admob, facebook-audience-network

> "ld: Linking globals named 'fbad_Cocos2DGetGLViewController': symbol
>   multiply defined! for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

I'm getting this error in XCode build project have two **SDKs "GoogleAdMob SDK Unity" and "FacebookAudienceNetwork" Unity**.

Deleting *-ObjC flag* from other linker flags won’t work for me.

Is there anybody can help me fix that issue?

Single SDK build either its GoogleAdMOb Unity or FacebookAudienceNetwork Unity don't have any issue.

Adding both generate this error:

> ""ld: Linking globals named 'fbad_Cocos2DGetGLViewController': symbol
>   multiply defined! for architecture arm64"